# Function that describes the average running time of insertion sort

Tags: insertion-sort

I was wondering if it is possible for someone to explain some stuff on insertion sort to me, regarding its different cases in running time.

I understand that it is a a comparison-based sorting algorithm, so only their relative ordering matters and not the value of the input. I have grasped the concept of best case where `tj=1` and running time is linear, and worst case where `tj=j` and running time is quadratic.

What I don't get is the average case, where I assume `tj=j/2`. What I can't find is the function of `n`, where `n` is the length of the array. Let's say the array is `[1,1,0,0]`. I would assume that it is not the worst case since `A[0]` and `A[1]` are `tj=1`, so that would make it average case where `tj=j/2`, but what would n be in this case? `n/2`? or `n/2+1`?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The term you're looking for is [Big O notation](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), which is a measure of the *order* (i.e. average running time for *n* elements) of a function. Insertion sort is an [*O(n^2)*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort), so its average running time is exponential.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I was referring to the T(n) of the algorithm before we get to the Big 0 notation.